Composition of Data.Dynamic functions in Haskell
I have some functions in Haskell with various types.
I need to keep them in some heterogenous list so use something like Data.Dynamic.
I want to take functions from this list and compose them together to get a new function with different type.
e.g. I have the functions addDoubles :: Double -> Double -> Double and fromInt :: Int -> Double then I could compose a function like composedFn = (. fromInt) . addDoubles . fromInt this should then be saved as a Dynamic with type Int -> Int -> Double
I am having trouble getting ghc to believe that the types are all correct though.
Any help whatsoever is really appreciated :)
Like I said I have tried Data.Dynamic ...
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
import Data.Dynamic
import Data.Data


fromInt :: Int -> Double
fromInt = fromIntegral

addDubs :: Double -> Double -> Double
addDubs = (+)

-- I want to store many fns in some collection all with different types
myfuncs :: [Dynamic]
myfuncs = [toDyn fromInt, toDyn addDubs]


-- I want to be able to combine these functions to get new types
partialApplyFns2Fn :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> (d -> b -> e) -> (c -> a -> e)
partialApplyFns2Fn r l f = (. r) . f . l


combineHard :: Dynamic -> Dynamic -> Dynamic -> Maybe Dynamic
combineHard d1 d2 d3 = do 
    f1 <- fromDynamic d1 :: Maybe (Int -> Double)
    f2 <- fromDynamic d2 :: Maybe (Int -> Double)
    f3 <- fromDynamic d3 :: Maybe (Double -> Double -> Double)
    return $ toDyn ((. f1) . f3 . f2)

This works, however, I don't want to hardcode these types. Elsewhere in the code I will know these types and also the TypeRep of the combined Fn so would ideally like to do something like this ...
combineDynams :: (TypeRep, Dynamic) -> (TypeRep, Dynamic) -> (TypeRep, Dynamic) -> TypeRep -> Maybe Dynamic 
combineDynams (tr1, f1) (tr2, f2) (tr3, f3) targetTypeRep = do 
    f1' <- fromDynamic f1 :: Maybe tr1
    f2' <- fromDynamic f2 :: Maybe tr2
    f3' <- fromDynamic f3 :: Maybe tr3
    return $ toDyn (partialApplyFns2Fn f1' f2' f3')

but it obviously doesn't work.
I have also tried GADTs with a cast but with similar problems.
data AnyFunc where
  AnyUnary :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => (a -> b) -> AnyFunc
  AnyBinary :: (Typeable c, Typeable d, Typeable e) => (c -> d -> e) -> AnyFunc


-- Function that checks type compatibility at runtime
anyFuncMaker :: AnyFunc -> AnyFunc -> AnyFunc -> Maybe AnyFunc
anyFuncMaker (AnyUnary l) (AnyUnary r) (AnyBinary f) =
  case cast f of
    Just f' -> Just $ AnyBinary (partialApplyFns2Fn l r f')
    Nothing -> Nothing  -- Type mismatch

the type error for the GADT section is:
The type variable ‘e0’ is ambiguous
    • In the expression: cast f
      In the expression:
        case cast f of
          Just f' -> Just $ AnyBinary (partialApplyFns2Fn l r f')
          Nothing -> Nothing
      In an equation for ‘anyFuncMaker’:
          anyFuncMaker (AnyUnary l) (AnyUnary r) (AnyBinary f)
            = case cast f of
                Just f' -> Just $ AnyBinary (partialApplyFns2Fn l r f')
                Nothing -> Nothing

if I AllowAmbigousTypes:
 • Could not deduce (Typeable e0) arising from a use of ‘cast’
      from the context: (Typeable a, Typeable b)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   AnyUnary :: forall a b.
                               (Typeable a, Typeable b) =>
                               (a -> b) -> AnyFunc,
                 in an equation for ‘anyFuncMaker’
     
      or from: (Typeable a1, Typeable b1)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   AnyUnary :: forall a b.
                               (Typeable a, Typeable b) =>
                               (a -> b) -> AnyFunc,
                 in an equation for ‘anyFuncMaker’

For the Data.Dynamic code
No instance for (Typeable tr1)
    arising from a use of ‘fromDynamic’
• In a stmt of a 'do' block: f1' <- fromDynamic f1 :: Maybe tr1
  In the expression:
    do f1' <- fromDynamic f1 :: Maybe tr1
       f2' <- fromDynamic f2 :: Maybe tr2
       f3' <- fromDynamic f3 :: Maybe tr3
       return $ toDyn (partialApplyFns2Fn f1' f2' f3')
  In an equation for ‘combineDynams’:
      combineDynams (tr1, f1) (tr2, f2) (tr3, f3) targetTypeRep
        = do f1' <- fromDynamic f1 :: Maybe tr1
             f2' <- fromDynamic f2 :: Maybe tr2
             f3' <- fromDynamic f3 :: Maybe tr3

but I also assume that :: Maybe tr1 etc. is complete garbage!

Skipping the AnyFunc stuff and starting from your first code example, something like the following will work:
combineHard' :: Dynamic -> Dynamic -> Dynamic -> Maybe Dynamic
combineHard' (Dynamic (Fun a b) f)
             (Dynamic (Fun c d) g)
             (Dynamic (Fun d' (Fun b' e)) h)
  | Just HRefl <- b `eqTypeRep` b'
  , Just HRefl <- d `eqTypeRep` d'
  , Just HRefl <- typeRep @Type `eqTypeRep` typeRepKind a
  , Just HRefl <- typeRep @Type `eqTypeRep` typeRepKind b
  , Just HRefl <- typeRep @Type `eqTypeRep` typeRepKind c
  , Just HRefl <- typeRep @Type `eqTypeRep` typeRepKind d
  , Just HRefl <- typeRep @Type `eqTypeRep` typeRepKind e
  = Just (Dynamic (Fun c (Fun a e)) (\x y -> h (g x) (f y)))

main = do
  let Just f = combineHard' (toDyn fromInt) (toDyn fromInt) (toDyn addDubs)
  print $ f `dynApp` toDyn @Int 1 `dynApp` toDyn @Int 2

See dynApply in Data.Dynamic for a simpler example of the technique, but the basic idea is to use eqTypeRep calls to provide evidence that the argument types all have kind Type and match where necessary for the lambda expression to type check.

I wonder why this approach needs typeRepKind and Type, while my uglier one using typeRep @(->) does not. Is it because Fun is too general?

It looks like Fun generalizes over runtime representations of its argument and return value (i.e., TYPE rep instead of Type = TYPE LiftedRep).  In contrast, the type application @(->) defaults to kind Type -> Type -> Type, which automatically infers all the right kinds for the arguments and return values.

I think technically the final test on typeRepKind e isn't needed... but the situations where leaving it off would actually change anything do seem pretty niche.

In the case of your GADT-based solution, I'm getting the error:
• Could not deduce ‘Typeable e0’ arising from a use of ‘cast’
  from the context: (Typeable a, Typeable b)

It seems that the cast needs a bit more guidance for the final result type of the two-argument function. GHC is not convinced that when we cast the two-argument function, the result type is the same as the one from the original function.
We need to "bind" the type in order to refer to it. We can do that with this ungainly helper function:
anyFuncMaker' :: AnyFunc -> AnyFunc -> AnyFunc -> Maybe AnyFunc
anyFuncMaker' (AnyUnary l) (AnyUnary r) (AnyBinary f) = AnyBinary <$> annoyingAux l r f
  where 
  annoyingAux 
        :: forall a b c d d' b' e . 
           (Typeable a, Typeable b, Typeable c, Typeable d, Typeable d', Typeable b', Typeable e) 
        => (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> (d' -> b' -> e) -> Maybe (c -> a -> e)
  annoyingAux l' r' g = 
    case cast g of
        Just g' -> Just $ (partialApplyFns2Fn l' r' g')
        Nothing -> Nothing 
anyFuncMaker' _ _ _ = Nothing


Maybe there's a simpler way to define the helper function, but I'm not sure. Instead of a helper function, we can simplify the definition using type abstractions in patterns (GHC 9.2 onwards):
anyFuncMaker'' :: AnyFunc -> AnyFunc -> AnyFunc -> Maybe AnyFunc
anyFuncMaker'' (AnyUnary l) (AnyUnary r) (AnyBinary @_ @_ @e f) =
  case cast f of
    Just f' -> Just $ AnyBinary @_ @_ @e (partialApplyFns2Fn l r f')
    Nothing -> Nothing 
anyFuncMaker'' _ _ _ = Nothing


I'm posting my horrible solution, even if I just saw K.A. Buhr's one which is on the same line but more elegant. Mine uses more general tools, but this generality is not truly needed and only makes things more complex.
Perhaps this can be useful to solve similar but more involved tasks.
import Type.Reflection

combineDynams :: Dynamic -> Dynamic -> Dynamic -> Maybe Dynamic 
combineDynams (Dynamic (App (App fun1 a) b) x1) 
              (Dynamic (App (App fun2 c) d) x2)
              (Dynamic (App (App fun3 d') (App (App fun3' b') e)) x3) 
  | Just HRefl <- eqTypeRep (typeRep @(->)) fun1
  , Just HRefl <- eqTypeRep (typeRep @(->)) fun2
  , Just HRefl <- eqTypeRep (typeRep @(->)) fun3
  , Just HRefl <- eqTypeRep (typeRep @(->)) fun3'
  , Just HRefl <- eqTypeRep d d'
  , Just HRefl <- eqTypeRep b b'
  = withTypeable a $ withTypeable c $ withTypeable e $
    Just $ toDyn (partialApplyFns2Fn x1 x2 x3)
combineDynams _ _ _ = Nothing

Here, I first pattern match the typeReps to ensure that types have the form fun1 a b, fun2 c d and fun3 d' (fun3' b' e). Then I ensure that all the fun actually represent ->. (For this, I should have used Fun as in the other answer, which is simpler. But when all you know is how to use a hammer...) Then, I ensure b = b' && d = d' so that types match.
Finally, I noticed I need a few withTypeable to convince the compiler that toDyn can be used. Using the Dynamic constructor is an alternative which requires manually reconstructing the typeRep, but avoids the withTypeable.
